# Random Walk Question - How to determine faster method

Tags: probability, expected-value, random-walk

A man had too much to drink and is standing on a bridge that is 100ft long. He’s currently at the 15th foot, but has a tendency to either move forward or backward one meter with a 50% chance for each step that he takes. What are the chances that he’ll make it to the end of the bridge before he returns to the beginning. Also, how many steps is he expected to take to reach either end of the bridge?

The solution that I'm thinking of is starting a gambler's ruin at 15 and determining the probability of getting back to the start and subtracting 1 from that to get the first solution. However, it's very time intensive and thought there may be a faster method?

Also as a side note, what concepts could I study to get better at these types of questions :).

Comment: Random walks invariably assume gaussian brownian motion. As Mandelbrot notes in a paper, assumptions other gaussian are possible. *Wilder* random walks should converge faster. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_states_of_randomness

Comment: The probability for a random walk with $\pm1$ steps of equal probability is easy to find using  a constant expected position.  That and the expected number of steps have been asked may times on this site

Comment: This is the *Binomial Random Walk.* Good keywords for research include absorbing barrier, (discrete) stochastic process, Brownian Motion, stopping time, Martingale, modern probability, and financial calculus.